# About CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I was writing some codes and I was refreshing the html page to look it is working or not. I wrote some codes again and after that I can see just the structure of the page and I started thinking that CSS in my code is not working  and this is my first questions so if I did something wrong I am sorry :)

Pastebin Links of CSS and HTML files:

HTML:
[html code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Yv9PZW5qZw/)

normalize.css
[normalize.css code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7fWtjfb5MR/)

custom.css
[custom.css code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/f4SrVZDVnt/)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a quick read of [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the section _"Help others reproduce the problem"_ in order to avoid your question from being closed. Cheers! :)

Comment: please tell us in the question, what you are trying to accomplish and what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely check the paths of your css files. But I guess they don't work because you have errors in them.

In "custom.css", .container misses a curly bracket.

In "normalize.css"

`ul, li{
  padding 0;
}`, you need to add :.